# How can I write a raw string of XML to a file reliably, to a base-64 encoded string?

Tags: c#, base64, streamreader, datacontractserializer, streamwriter

I have memory stream of raw XML produced by a DataContractSerializer. This string can be quite long, and generates files of 60mb+. I then read this into a string, and then encode in UTF8 bytes and then convert to a base 64 string. Here is a code snippet:

```
// serialize to a memory stream.
rawXML = new MemoryStream();

dcs = new DataContractSerializer(vToWrite.GetType(),
    null, 2147483647, false, false, null, new ClassResolver());

dcs.WriteObject(rawXML, vToWrite);
rawXML.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// read the stream into a raw string of XML
sr = new StreamReader(rawXML);
xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
rawXML.Close();
sr.Close();

// encode into base64
//bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
//encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);

// write string out
writer = File.CreateText(fullPath + "Module" + i + "D" +
    historicDataCount +  ".bin");

writer.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString)));// (encodedText);

writer.Close();
// end save mod day //
```

The problem i'm getting is that sometimes I run into a out of memory exception when either reading the stream into the xmlString or when writing the string out using the stream writer (Thats what 'writer' is by the way).

I'm not quite sure how to solve this. I think maybe reading and converting the original stream in 'chunks' maybe the way forward, but i'm not sure how this will affect the reading back in of the file.

Comment: I'm a little confused why you would read a raw byte stream into a string and then turn around and convert the string back to a raw byte stream. Why not have the DataContractSerializer write in UTF8, get the memory buffer from the MemoryStream, and base64 encode that? You would save yourself the memory for the string and for the temporary buffer allocated by the call to GetBytes.

Comment: How can I get the DataContractSerializer to write in UTF8?

Comment: You create an `XmlWriter` that defaults to UTF-8, and pass that to  `dcs.WriteObject`. So instead of writing directly to the `MemoryStream`, it writes to the `XmlWriter` that is backed by the `MemoryStream`. See the [Write overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573855.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that uses [System.Security.Cryptography.ToBase64Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform.aspx) and converts an array of bytes to base64 in chunks

```
// write string out
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);

using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(fullPath + "Module" + i + "D" + historicDataCount +  ".bin"))
    using (ToBase64Transform transformation = new ToBase64Transform())
    {                    
        byte[] buffer = new byte[transformation.OutputBlockSize];

        int i = 0;    
        while (data.Length - i > transformation.InputBlockSize)
        {
            transformation.TransformBlock(data, i, data.Length - i, buffer, 0);
            i += transformation.InputBlockSize;
            writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
        }

        // final block
        buffer = transformation.TransformFinalBlock(data, i, data.Length - i);
        writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `base64` converts three octets(bytes) into four encoded characters if you read multiple chunks of 3000 bytes (or any other 3 byte multiplier) there should be no problem

For more info about **base64 encoding** see **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64**

Comment: How can I be sure that the number of bytes i'll have will be a multiple of 3?

Comment: in fact base 64 know how to perform the padding when the last chunk of bytes is not a multiple of 3, see the link I have included